# Anything lost/reset when copying a sharepoint site?

Tags: permissions, copy-content

After copying a site to a new location, does anything get lost or reset?

For example, if I copy site "bar" from SiteCollection/bar to SiteCollection/foo/bar. Does the new copy preserve EVERYTHING from the old location? Including unique permissions?

Version = SharePoint 2013
Method = native "Content and structure" feature under Site Administration.

Comment: what method you are using to copy the site, import export, save as template or erd party?

Comment: @Waqas Sarwar MCSE  Hi sorry forgot to mention it. I'm using the native "Content and Structure" feature under Site Administration. Just did a testing, seems the new copy lost permission and inheriting everything. But If I do a MOVE instead of COPY, the moved site preserved everything?